# TableView heightForRowAtIndexPath select by tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I create a TableView customized (Create inside storyboard) some rows have 33 height, 78 height, 204 height. When I run my project the height of the rows were different from what I had drawn.

To solve this problem I put a tag on each row in the table and used the following command:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            return 56;
            break;

        case 1:
            return 44;
            break;

        case 2:
            return 34;
            break;

        case 3:
            return 172;
            break;

        default: return 204;
            break;
    }

}
```

But this code have a problem, I need to check **indexPath.row.tag** and not **indexPath.row** (When I try to use .tag Xcode don't compile)

How I can select the row by tag? or how can I make the height of the lines are the same as I had designed (without using the command: heightForRowAtIndexPath)?

**EDIT**

```
  menuItems = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20",@"21",@"22",@"23",@"24",@"25",@"26",@"27",@"28",@"29",@"30",@"31",@"32",@"33",@"34",@"35",@"36",@"37",@"38",@"39",@"40",@"41",@"42",@"43",@"44",@"45",@"46",@"47",@"48",@"49",@"50",@"51",@"52"];

        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView2 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            NSString *CellIdentifier = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }

            return cell;
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code?  I'm not sure you're referring to the proper cells in your storyboard.  You should be referring to them by their reuse identifier using a similar switch statement.

Comment: @d2burke, yes i edited my post now, my table have 52 rows...

Comment: Is this a dynamic tableview or static?

Comment: @Marc-AlexandreBérubé its a "dynamic Prototypes"

Comment: Well then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you probably have some logic to determine which cell type to use. You need to use that same logic inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and then return the height based on the cell type (and not tags inside an instanciated cell)

Comment: @HpTerm, I edited my post

Comment: Do you have 52 prototype cells defined in your storyboard!?

Comment: before I lay out a very comprehensive answer to this question, may I ask, do you have some very specific content that is to go into these cells, or is the content more or less the same? Meaning, do you plan to simply put varying lengths of text or some other standardized content?

Comment: I ask, because if so, this can all be pretty simple.  If indeed, you actually have 52 rows which are very different and require different controls and types of subviews, there is another way to handle that as well.  This is very important.

Comment: @Marc-AlexandreBérubé, Yes I have

Comment: @d2burke, so whats the simple way to solve this problem?